# Enable Ctrl+Alt+F1 Virtual Consoles in GNOME (Ubuntu 17.04+)

Tags: tty, virtual-console

In previous versions of Ubuntu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd> opened up virtual consoles. On Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> opens another GUI and the others do nothing.

How do I restore the old behavior?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm running Kubuntu v16.04 - not the version that you are - but I had to modify `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncomment `NAutoVTs=6` and restart.

Also, check `/etc/default/console-setup`, the line: `ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"`

Comment: Worked great! Note that if your don't want to restart you can also `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

Comment: @user2070305 in my case that command leads me to a non-responsive login screen, I had to force a reboot

Answer (score 1):

> the others do nothing.

On 17.10, the virtual terminals are there but invisible!  You can type blindly into them and they work:

```
Alt-Ctrl-F4   # switch to a VT
Enter
username    # typing blindly into black screen...
password
date >/tmp/foo
Alt-Ctrl-F1  # switch back to Wayland GUI
ls -l /tmp/foo  # it's there
```

Comment: > # typing blindly into black screen...

There is no black screen to type into.  It just remains on the gui.  At least when this issue presents itself.

Comment: It depends on your hardware: my two laptops behave different, one jumps into a blank screen, the other just keeps stuck in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out for Ubuntu 22.04, but it appears the arrangement of consoles has changed from what it was historically. Ctrl+Alt+F1 appears to be a persistent session for the login screen (to allow switching between multiple users, I think), Ctrl+Alt+F2 is the logged-in GUI session, and then Ctrl+Alt+F3 through Ctrl+Alt+F6 are additional consoles (though I suspect those may get consumed if more than one GUI user is logged in).