# Ubuntu 18.10 is stuck at loading screen after new installation

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth, virtual-console, sysrq

Very much like:

[Ubuntu 18.04 is stuck at loading screen after new installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/1033463/45156)

Except for being Ubuntu 18.10

The only way to interrupt a hung system like this, which simply never completes the boot process, is to use `REISUB`?

It's booted fine more than a few times.

see also:

[enable ctrl+alt+F1 virtual consoles in ubuntu gnome](https://askubuntu.com/q/911560/45156)

--------------------------meta-----------------------------------

*I wasn't able to get a virtual to a virtual console, unfortunately.*

For practical purposes, yes, "solved" problem in that I haven't had the problem since.  Either the underlying problem was resolved or it's just intermittent.

The only reason I haven't accepted the answer, which is an excellent answer, is that, should someone come here with the exact same problem, I'm not convinced they'll be able to get to a virtual console.  Which was rather the point of the question, being as other aspects were answered in the linked question, I believe.

Again, it's an excellent answer.  Not looking to detract from the answer.  I think I was correctly trying to access virtual consoles and it just wasn't working, but I can't say absolutely.  Which was the crux of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried what is written in answer? 18.10 and 18.04 are very much similar.

Comment: haven't rebooted yet.  that's the only option?  reisub and then enter grub?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the OS is not able to take you to the login screen.

Try this:

- Presst <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>/<kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> this should take you to tty
- Type: `$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/`
- Reboot
  After running this command, you hopefully shouldn't have any problems logging in.

Also insure the integrity of your login manager. You can do this by installing lightdm with:

```
$ sudo apt install lightdm
```

At the command configuration prompt select Lightdm.

You can toggle between the Lightdm login manager and the Gnome login manager with this command:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: I might not have been doing `ctrl` + `alt` + `F1`, I might have just been doing `ctrl` + `F1`.  Looks like a solution, thank you.  I hesitate to say it's an answer until I have the same problem again (hopefully not).

Comment: ctrl + alt + F2 until F6 is for accessing tty. ctrl + alt + F7 is for accessing the login screen. Try this solution and let me know

Comment: @KailashMallikarjun That's not true. I have GUI mode in F1 and F2 while CLI mode (TTY mode) in F3-F7. That varies system to system and configuration.

Comment: @Thufir Also apart from lightdm have you tried installing and configuring gdm (default login screen of gnome) again?

Comment: @Kulfy: You're right. It differs from system to system.
Thufir: Hope you were able to get a solution.

Comment: Only changing the greeter did the trick for me; does anybody know why gdm3 may suddenly not work anymore?